# How to repeat jQuery scroll function when scrollTop is less than "n" and when user scrolls down only

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a container with fixed position on page load and its height is equal to window height. It has to be positioned "fixed" (?) because overlay with text pops up over it when scroll is bigger than 1px and they both must have height equal to the window height.
If scrollTop is larger than half of the window height, page automatically scrolls to next section and fixed position is removed from that container.

Here is the code:

```
$(window).on('scroll.a', function () {

var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
var scrollTopMask = $(window).scrollTop();
var slideAfter = windowheight/2;

if (scrollTopMask > slideAfter) {
  $('.container').addClass('not-fixed');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#nextSection').offset().top
    }, 700);

    $(window).off('scroll.a');

} else if (scrollTopMask < slideAfter) {
  $('.container').removeClass('not-fixed');
}});
```

The problem is that I have to `off()` the scroll function in order to continue scrolling after the function has been executed and conditions met. Is there any way to restart function when `scrollTop === 0` and user scrolls down again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a flag to store the state if the user has scrolled past `slideAfter`. When it is `false`, you continue with the logic, otherwise you simply return:

```js
var hasScrolledPast = false;
$(window).on('scroll.a', function () {

  var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
  var scrollTopMask = $(window).scrollTop();
  var slideAfter = windowheight/2;

  if (scrollTopMask > slideAfter) {

    // If user has already scrolled past, don't do anything
    if (hasScrolledPast)
      return;

    $('.container').addClass('not-fixed');
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#nextSection').offset().top
      }, 700);

    // Update flag so that we know user has scrolled past
    hasScrolledPast = true;

  } else if (scrollTopMask < slideAfter) {
    $('.container').removeClass('not-fixed');

    // Reset scroll past flag
    hasScrolledPast = false;
  }

});
```

---

**Suggestion**: your user might load a page where his/her scrollposition is already beyond your threshold. However, the flag will not be updated if that happens, since the scroll event has not been fired on the viewport. In that case, what I suggest is that the logic be abstracted into a function, and you simply use that function as a callback on the scroll event, and also call it on page load:

```js
var hasScrolledPast = false;
var scrollLogic = function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();
  var scrollTopMask = $(window).scrollTop();
  var slideAfter = windowheight/2;

  if (scrollTopMask > slideAfter) {

    // If user has already scrolled past, don't do anything
    if (hasScrolledPast)
      return;

    $('.container').addClass('not-fixed');
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#nextSection').offset().top
      }, 700);

    // Update flag so that we know user has scrolled past
    hasScrolledPast = true;

  } else if (scrollTopMask < slideAfter) {
    $('.container').removeClass('not-fixed');

    // Reset scroll past flag
    hasScrolledPast = false;
  }
};

// Evaluate on scroll
$(window).on('scroll.a', scrollLogic);

// Evaluate on page load/DOM ready
scrollLogic();
```

Comment: That's perfect! Works great, and thank you for the suggestion, it's very useful!